# how can I fetch data from graphql in my resolver

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Within my resolver I seem to be unable to fetch connected data

this works in the graphql playground (prisma) but I am unsure of the syntax about how to form a resolver in apollo server

```
// my typedef for activity is

type Activity {
    id: ID! @id
    ActivityType: ActivityType!
    title: String!
    date: DateTime
    user: User!
    distance: Float!
    distance_unit: Unit!
    duration: Float!
    elevation: Float
    elevation_unit: Unit
    createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
    updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt

// and my resolver currently looks like this

async activity(parent, args, ctx, info) {
        const foundActivity = await ctx.db.query.activity({
            where: {
                id: args.id
            }
        });
        // todo fetch user data from query
        console.log(foundActivity);
    }

// where db has been placed onto the ctx (context)
// the CL gives all of the data for Activity apart from the user

// in the playground I would do something like this

query activity {
  activity(where: {
    id: "cjxxow7c8si4o0b5314f9ibek"
  }){
    title
    user {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}

// but I do not know how to specify what is returned in my resolver.

console.log(foundActivity) gives:

{ id: 'cjxxpuh1bsq750b53psd2c77d',
  ActivityType: 'CYCLING',
  title: 'Test Activity',
  date: '2019-07-10T20:21:27.681Z',
  distance: 13.4,
  distance_unit: 'KM',
  duration: 90030,
  elevation: 930,
  elevation_unit: 'METERS',
  createdAt: '2019-07-10T20:48:50.879Z',
  updatedAt: '2019-07-10T20:48:50.879Z' }
```

Prisma is the DB ORM and then I have an Apollo-Server 2 server running on top of that. Unfortunately, stack overflow also thinks that there is too much code on this post so I will have to waffle on about inconsequential gibberish due to the fact that their system can't handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement a resolver for `Activity.user`. Unfortunately your entity does not seem to contain a reference to the user. First, add the user connection to your Prisma data model. Then implement a resolver for `Activity.user`. I am not very familiar with Prisma 1 but this naive implementation should already do what you want:

```js
let resolvers = {
  Query: {
    // ...
  },
  Activity: {
    user(parent, args, ctx) {
      return ctx.db.query.activity({ id: parent.id }).user();
    }
  }
}
```

Find out more about resolving relations in Prisma [here](https://www.prisma.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-common-resolver-patterns-ct08/)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and for taking the time. I have found a different route, shown below, but you put me on to the path.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was incredibly simple:
I just add a second argument to the query (after the "where" with a gql tag of the data shape to be returned so my code now looks like:

```
const foundActivity = await ctx.db.query.activity(
        {
            where: {
                id: args.id
            }
        },
        `{id title user { id name }}`
    );
```

Comment: The same could maybe be archieved by supplying the info argument (4th argument to the resolver) as 2nd argument to the DB call. This will only fetch the user if it is actually requested in the initial request.